# Django Shell in Eclipse not starting

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, django-shell

I am getting this error message when I try to run the shell from Eclipse Neon while I can successfully run the Django shell from command window. I am using Python 3.4 and Django 1.10. Any idea where the problem is?

[image]

**WSGI file:**

```
'''
WSGI config for MyProject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
'''

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyProject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: I don't know why @Hybrid deleted his answer because "You have an accidental indentation in your wsgi.py file"

Comment: But then again this question is off topic because it's a typo

Comment: @e4c5  "wsgi.py" file is generated by django and I have not touched it, so I doubt it is a typo. plus, I can run it from command prompt.

Comment: Well the error still says extra space so why don't you open it and see?

Comment: @e4c5 I checked "wsgi.py" file, there is no unexpected indent. Should I look somewhere else?

Comment: why not update the post with that file

Comment: @e4c5 I just updated it

Comment: that does look ok unless there is a hidden character somewhere

Comment: @e4c5 the error message is:  File "<input>", line 1
   application = get_wsgi_application()
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent I think it is a different file, but I cannot figure out where the file is.

Comment: I would suggest opening a console and starting the same Environment:

Paste in each line as in the output window and see if you get a fail with something else: e.g.

AttributeError: module 'django.core.management' has no attribute 'setup_environ' which version of Django are you using?

Comment: compare your version to the following:

django.get_version() < '1.5'

django.get_version() >= '1.7'

Comment: @ PythonTester I am using Django 1.10 and since I got frustrated I built the project from scratch and tried not to use Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive This is a known bug in Eclipse Pydev.

[https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev](https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/)

> Fixed for 5.6
>
> Git: 2c8cd03 2017-03-12 Fabio Zadrozny #PyDev-752: Django version not
>   detected if > 1.10

And a fix has been posted for it.

You could try start a python shell as normal, then:

```
import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
import os; os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<Project Name>.settings'; import django
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('<path to your project>'))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Replace 'Project Name' with your project name and 'path to your project' with your path

alternatively,  use a pre 1.10 version of Django i.e 1.7